# Label won't work when used inside FooterTemplate/Panel/SecurePanel/Div

Tags: asp.net, label

Run through Site_materials table, any matches found store them in 'NumberOFDeliveries',
which is the ID of the label that should display them on screen.

```
 //DELIVERIES
        int NumberOfDeliveries = (from Deliveries in db.Site_Materials
                              where Deliveries.Diary_Entry_Id == this.DiaryEntryId
                              select Deliveries).ToList().Count();
        if (NumberOfDeliveries > 0)
        {
            NoOfDeliveriesOnSite.Text = System.Convert.ToString(NumberOfDeliveries);
        }
        else
        {
            NoOfDeliveriesOnSite.Text = "0";
        }
```

If I use the below label in my aspx page t displays as expected. But I have a problem trying to display it where i want... inside FooterTemplate/Panel/SecurePanel/Div

```
<FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="AllLinks" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="600px" >
                            <mesh:SecurePanel runat="server" ID="EmployeeLink" CssClass="SmallBoxLink" WebMasters="true" Admins="true" Clients="true" Employees="true">
                                <div style="height:25px; margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px;">
    <asp:Label ID="Delivery" runat="server" Text="Deliveries=" /><asp:Label ID="NoOfDeliveriesOnSite" runat="server" />
```

As I said this code works fine and displays the correct amount(When used at diff places on the aspx page) BUT when i try to display it where I want I get the error:
from the cs. page stating 'NoOfDeliveriesOnSite' does not exist.

any ideas as to why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's in the footer, you will need to set the control number to -1.  In this example, i have a label in the footer that  I want to get a handle on:

```
dim myLabel as label
myLable = myDataRepeater.Controls(myDataRepeater.Controls.Count - 1).FindControl("lableName")
```

If there is a control you're trying to find within the user control, you may need to add a notehr .FindControl method Ie:

```
myLable = myDataRepeater.Controls(myDataRepeater.Controls.Count - 1).FindControl("lableName").findControls("anotherControl")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find controls inside whatever container they're in.

You will want to add this above the code sample that you gave in your question, so that your reference to that variable will be valid:

```
SecurePanel EmployeeLink = (SecurePanel)AllLinks.FindControl("EmployeeLink");
Label NoOfDeliveriesOnSite = (Label)EmployeeLink.FindControl("NoOfDeliveriesOnSite");
```

Depending on what you're `FooterTemplate` is for (`GridView`, `FormView`, etc), you will probably need to find the "AllLinks" `Panel` inside that first as well.